# How to remap CapsLock to Ctrl in Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, xubuntu

I tried doing it like follows (in autostart):

```
setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"
```

and it works, but only for a while - then the setting is reset back to original state. How can I make it persistent?

I use `xfce4-xkb-plugin` as my input language switcher, but it doesn't seem to have an option to set caps key function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found what I was seeking for. The solution: remove xfce keyboard applet (didn't need to deinstall it, just deleting it from panel worked), install xxkb. Make sure the `~/.xxkbrc` contents look something like this:

```
XXkb.mainwindow.geometry: 20x20+0+0
XXkb.mainwindow.label.background: black
XXkb.mainwindow.label.foreground: white
XXkb.mainwindow.label.font: -misc-*-r-*-14-*
XXkb.mainwindow.label.text.1: en
XXkb.mainwindow.label.text.2: ru
XXkb.controls.add_when_start: yes
XXkb.controls.two_state: no
XXkb.button.enable: no
```

And add the following to run at your session startup:

```
xxkb &
setxkbmap -layout us,<your layout> -option "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,ctrl:nocaps"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the setxkbmap option in `XKBOPTIONS` in `/etc/default/keyboard`. That file is also  when you run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, however running that command does not interactively let you choose to swap Caps Lock and Ctrl, so you will need to edit the file by hand.

Comment: I already tried that - nothing changed.

Comment: Are you seeing the same thing as this blogger did? http://tinkerplanet.com/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-keyboard-layout-persistence-problems/

Comment: Doesn't seem so. Let me try again, I'll post the detailed symptoms of what happens when I try setting XKBOPTIONS.

Comment: So, I added option, ran `dpkg-reconfigure`. At first, everything is great, but I lost the ability to change keyboard layout (it was deleted from layouts list). I go to keyboard applet (xfce4-xkb-plugin), set up new layout, set the key combination to change the layout (left ctrl + left shift). Now, language change works - but caps lock is back to original function.

Comment: Setting `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` in `/etc/default/keyboard` is system-wide and requires a reboot (or at least restarting X). The question's `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` will work for the current session but won't survive a reboot, so do both. When you reboot, the system-wide change from this answer will kick in.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to create a file named `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals/keyboard/kbd/%gconf.xml` with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gconf>
       <entry name="options" mtime="1360937304" type="list" ltype="string">
               <li type="string">
                       <stringvalue>ctrl       ctrl:swapcaps</stringvalue>
               </li>
       </entry>
</gconf>
```

If that file already exists, or if you prefer to do it the manual way using the GUI, click the settings cog in the top right corner, choose System Settings, then Keyboard Layout, click Options, expand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> position and choose Swap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's Xfce, not Gnome. They don't have such option in Xfce :(

Comment: Oh, that is correct. My bad.